# `npm install -g nodemon` doesn't install nodemon

Tags: node.js, windows-10, nodemon

Nodemon has been working on my node.js websites on Windows 10 for months without any problem. Suddenly when I execute `nodemon` it says

> bash: nodemon: command not found

When I try to reinstall it with `npm install -g nodemon`, it reports:

```
C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon -> C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js

> nodemon@1.19.4 postinstall C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\nodemon\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ nodemon@1.19.4
updated 1 package in 7.35s
```

When I check if it is installed with `npm list -g --depth=0`, it reports that it is there:

```
C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- browser-sync@2.24.7
+-- less@3.9.0
+-- less-watch-compiler@1.13.0
+-- nodemon@1.19.4
+-- npm@6.4.1
+-- tsun@0.3.8
+-- typescript@2.9.2
`-- windows-build-tools@5.0.0
```

I've tried `npm uninstall nodemon` and reinstalling it but to no avail.

**How can I get nodemon to work again on Windows 10?**

Comment: Check whether nodemon actually wound up in a folder that is listed in your PATH environment variable, which might need revising to still include npm's bin folder.

Comment: Could be something up with your npm cache Try `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: @DanStarns `npm cache clean --force` didn't work, it still can't find nodemon even after reinstall

Comment: @TomBoutell, I found the environment path `C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.bin` which doesn't exist (?), and so added `C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin` but nodemon still can't be found (I exited and reopented Git bash)